# Commentary with a Single Block

Tags: comments

With [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) I've set the `commentstring` for markdown:

```
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal commentstring=<!--\ %s\ -->
```

When I visually select the lines and `gc`

```
a
b
c
```

I get

```
<!-- a -->
<!-- b -->
<!-- c -->
```

where I'd prefer a single block like

```
<!-- 
a
b
c 
-->
```

Is this possible with this or another plugin?

Comment: Commentary explicitly uses single-line comments (easier to parse and handle, every time), so I doubt it can do what you’re after.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @D. Ben Knoble - I switched to [tcomment_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim)

```
Plug 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'
[..]


let g:tcomment#block_fmt_xml = {
            \ 'commentstring': "<!--%s-->\n",
            \ 'replacements': g:tcomment#replacements_xml
            \ }
call tcomment#type#Define('markdown', g:tcomment#inline_fmt_xml )
call tcomment#type#Define('markdown_block', g:tcomment#block_fmt_xml )
```

I've changed the `commentstring` so I does not prefix any spaces.